# How can I add a CPS Project System as reference in another project type in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I need to use a CPS project system that generates a dll file as a reference in both a c# project and a c++ project, but when I add the project as reference in those projects, the IDE throws me an exception:

`A reference to myCpsProject could not be added`

I think it's because my CPS project system needs another capability, but I don't know how to implement it. How can I fix this error?

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: When I add the cps project as reference in a c# or c++ project, the VS 2017 only throws a window with an exception that says "a reference to myCpsProject could not be added".